# Нагрузка на сервер и JS фреймворки

Tags: javascript, сервер

При использовании Angular*,Vue.js и так далее, на стороне сервера нужно только выплюнуть данные, а клиентская часть сформирует страницу. Как это влияет на производительность?? По идее некоторая нагрузка с сервера должна спадать, или это ошибочная мысль, и формирование страницы не такая уж и ресурсоемкая операция?

Comment: Основые плюсы отвязки клиентского GUI от сервера в другом. Например, при такой архитектуре для разработки мобильного клиента, серверная часть практически не нуждается в изменениях.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от используемого сервера и от того как напишите. В целом нагрузка должна уменьшиться.

Еще сильнее она уменьшится если для раздачи статических файлов, которых у вас станет много, поставите специальный веб-сервер, например Nginx. Но это зависит от того, какой сервер у вас сейчас, к примеру IIS на nginx заменять не обязательно.

Проблемы могут возникнуть если вы будете делать слишком много запросов к серверу. Пара (десятков) запросов к серверу при каждой загрузке страницы убьет всю выгоду от отсутствия динамической генерации страницы на сервере.

Также проблем можно ожидать от "тяжелых" серверных фреймворков, которые будут делать лишнюю работу на простых запросах.

Answer (score 0):

С сервера нагрузка спадет, но вот почувствуете ли Вы это или нет, зависит от его нагруженности в принципе.

Если система высоко нагруженная, то это будет чувствоваться, а если нет - и эффект будет практически не заметен.